Connect to a Power BI XMLA endpoint using R without installing extra software
I see a lot of questions on stackoverflow about connecting to XMLA endpoints using Python, but I dont see many resources for R.  I'd love to connect to a Power Bi XMLA endpoint using R.
I see articles like this walking you through it, but that requires downloading their proprietary .jar driver that you have to pay for.
I also see stack questions like this for python, which mention using "olap".  There is an R package for connecting that way called "olapR", but it appears to not be a 'normal' R package (in the sense that you can install it from cran or github), and appears to be installed when you get MS SQL server, which would be a pain to install on my work computer.
Are there any other ways to connect?  On the Power Bi side I should have all the prerequisites (Premium workspace, found the XMLA server link etc...).
So to summarize, if I wanted to connect to a Power BI XMLA endpoint using R and lets say list tables available... is there a way to do that without installing extra software?

Maybe interface to this python solution using {reticulate}? Awkward though.

depending on what you need, a lot of the functionality people typically associate with the XMLA endpoint is available in the Power BI REST APIs, including the ability to execute DAX queries and get results.
